# Is it possible to connect two uswitches using more than one cable?

Tags: networking, switch, bonding

In theory (I have not successfully tried it yet), you can bind two ethernet interfaces and make them act as one (sharing/balancing the load) in linux machines, (theoretically) doubling the speed.

I was discussing with a friend if this would be possible to do with switches.

Connecting two unmanaged switches (let's say, 10/100) with 4 cables, would give a theoretical link between switches of 40/400, or will they just use one of them and ignore the rest?

Do managed switches have an option to enable this kind of thing?

I wanted to try this but one of the two unmanaged switches I had broke down, and I don't have any managed switches to try this on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature called "link aggregation" and supported by most of modern switches

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know that. Thank you!